# Saving data from a Non-SQL Object Variable to SQL database With SSIS and C#

Tags: c#, ssis

I am working on a solution that fetches files from an SFTP server, Save the Files Metadata in the DB(Name, Size, Date), download the files, decrypt them, Process them then mark, their status in the Db as Processed so that we don't download them again. At the moment I am using Foreach loop and Execute sql task to save the file metadata in the db. As the number of files increase, it is taking so long to loop through each file, skip existing file and insert new file metadata in the files table. I am looking for a more efficient way to do this. Any Ideas?

What I have tried Using Script Component. I think I could be using Using the wrong data adapter. Attached is the error I am getting

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
  {
     OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     da.Fill(dt, Variables.Filelist);

          foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
              FilesOutputBuffer.AddRow();
              FilesOutputBuffer.Name = string.Parse(dr["Name"].ToString());
              FilesOutputBuffer.Size = int.Parse(dr["Size"].ToString());
              FilesOutputBuffer.Date = DateTime.Parse(dr["Date"].ToString());
             }
     }
```

[image]

Comment: We do this a LOT with processing files where we get files each day and process them.  Our solution is to create a folder in the network drive and after we import / process the file we MOVE the file to an archive folder.  Then we dont have to loop through files at all, we just grab files in the direcorty and if it is in there we know it has not been processed yet.  You can do that with a file task to move them.  Doing it this way is much easier and you dont have to loop through files or anything.  If for some reason you need to re-run a file you can just stick it back in the directory

Comment: Actually remote files will take longer to process, bring them to where SSIS runs. Parallelize the processing by using more than one package at a time writing to different staging tables to avoid locking. Once the data is in the database push all into the final destination.

Comment: @ Brad. Thanks. I have already Implemented all the solution and it is workng. However I am looking for way to optimize it.  Like I had mentioned, I fetch the file metadata from SFTP server  and save them in an object variable then use foreach loop and Execute SQL task to insert the metadata into an SQL table. What I am looking for is a way to use this object variable as a source using script component.

Comment: @Brad why not writing your comment as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this using script component as a source. It only has a bit of C# code.

1. 1.Open the data flow task then drag and drop the script Component from to toolbox. When prompted to Specify how to use the Script Component, choose the first option (Source). then Click Ok.
2. Open the Script Component by double clicking. On the Read only Variable, select the object variable that will have the file names.
3. Go to Input and output section to define your columns and datatype.
4. Click Edit Script and paste the following C# code to the "create new output" section and voila, you are good to go.

This ended up improving performance by 40mins

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)Variables.FileList;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            Output0Buffer.AddRow();
            Output0Buffer.FileName = (String)dr[0];
            Output0Buffer.FileDate = (DateTime)dr[1];
            Output0Buffer.FileSize = Convert.ToInt32(dr[2]);
            Output0Buffer.DownloadDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Per suggestion moving my comment to answer/solution:

We do this a LOT with processing files where we get files each day and process them. Our solution is to create a folder in the network drive and after we import / process the file we MOVE the file to an archive folder. Then we dont have to loop through files at all, we just grab files in the directory and if it is in there we know it has not been processed yet. You can do that with a file task to move them. Doing it this way is much easier and you dont have to loop through files or anything. If for some reason you need to re-run a file you can just stick it back in the directory .

Comment: Does anyone have an idea on how to go about this? I.e use an Script Component as a source from an object Variable(That is NOT from Execute SQl task) result set

Comment: Look at the File System Task.  You dont need C# it is built in